# Configure ASP.net 4.5 for Charting

Tags: asp.net, charts

I need a way to configure ASP.net 4.5 for Charting.

Error in line:

```
     <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
     </assemblies>
```

Error code:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=30;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
      assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
     </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you install the chart controls? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422

Comment: @causita Chart Controls don't have to be installed for ASP.NET 4+ according to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Charting comes built in to ASP.NET 4+. Unfortunately, there are still some glitches with adding it to projects. The easiest way I found to add charts was to actually drag the item out of the Toolbox into an aspx page. It did some background operations to the Web.config file and the page I added the control to.

Here's what it added to the Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here's what it added to the aspx file to which I added the control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Unfortunately, it still did not work as is. I had to make a couple more adjustments to the Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Abandoned. Went the flot with AJAX option.